# Silly trouble expressing recursive formulas?

Tags: functions, function-construction, recursion

I am trying to code the following formulas:

> [image]

I did it in the following way:

```
S[u_] := 2.94/(u + 520 E^(-0.14 u))
u[n_] := 1/\[CapitalSigma] Sum[X[i, x], {i, 2, n}];
X[1, n_ + 1] := S[u[n]] Sum[b[i] X[i, n], {i, 1, 13}]
X[i_ + 1, n_ + 1] := s[i] X[i, n]
```

But when I type `X[1,5]`, it returns `X[1,5]` instead of some summation expression. This doesn't happens with `u[7]` tho. See:

> [image]

What can be done? I tried to write X with $n,i$ and $n-1,i-1$ but it also doesn't work. Can I define it just as the formulas above?

Comment: ``X[i_ +1, n_ + 1]`` will apply to expression like ``X[3 + 1, 5, + 1]``. What you want is for ``X`` to apply to ``X[4, 6]``, and then properly adapt the values (minus one). Therefore: ``X[1, n_] := S[u[n - 1]] Sum[b[i] X[i, n - 1], {i, 1, 13}]; X[i_, n_] := s[i - 1] X[i - 1, n - 1] ``

Comment: However, you also have a mistake in the limits of the sum in the definition of ``u`` (should be ``{i, 2, 13}``). Finally, there the definition for ``X[1, 1]`` is missing.

Comment: If you want to retain the syntax (just for convenience), you can do `With[{n = nplusone - 1}, X[i_, nplusone_] := <definition involving n>]`. This will replace all `n`s with `nplusone -1`, then set the definition.